# JMeter : Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided

Tags: firefox, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Need help as I'm trying to create performance scenario using JMeter 5.6.2 and Firefox Driver Config on Corporate Machine but I'm getting error message :

*org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided, and no binary flag set on the command line.*

**Scenario need to be done :**

- Automate Microsoft login page using selenium with the help of *jp@gc - Firefox Driver Config* and *jp@gc - WebDriver Sampler*

**Configurations :**

- JMeter Version : 5.6.2
- Selenium-api Version : 4.10
- Geko-Driver Version : V0.33.0 - X64
- Plugins Manager is installed
- "jp@gc - Firefox Driver Config" and "jp@gc - WebDriver Sampler" installed
- Firefox Browser installed version : 117.0.1 (64-bit)
- Firefox Installation Path : C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Mozilla Firefox
- - **Note: I'm note able to change the browser.exe location to default or change in the system variables as it's a corporate machine and I don't have admin role**
- ** JMeter System Property file was edited to add the Divers path by using the following command : webdriver.gecko.driver=C:/Users/username/Downloads/DriversLatest/geckodriver.exe

**Detailed Error**

*Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: firefox, moz:debuggerAddress: true, moz:firefoxOptions: {profile: UEsDBBQACAgIAI5QNlcAAAAAAAA...}, proxy: Proxy(system)}]}]
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:140) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.10.0.jar:?]
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:96) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.10.0.jar:?]
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:68) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.10.0.jar:?]
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:163) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.10.0.jar:?]
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:196) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.10.0.jar:?]
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:171) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.10.0.jar:?]
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:531) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.10.0.jar:?]
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:227) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.10.0.jar:?]
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:154) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.10.0.jar:?]
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:151) ~[selenium-firefox-driver-4.10.0.jar:?]
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:146) ~[selenium-firefox-driver-4.10.0.jar:?]
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:130) ~[selenium-firefox-driver-4.10.0.jar:?]
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:125) ~[selenium-firefox-driver-4.10.0.jar:?]
at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.FirefoxDriverConfig.createBrowser(FirefoxDriverConfig.java:36) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-4.10.0.0.jar:?]
at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.FirefoxDriverConfig.createBrowser(FirefoxDriverConfig.java:15) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-4.10.0.0.jar:?]
at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.WebDriverConfig.getPreparedBrowser(WebDriverConfig.java:221) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-4.10.0.0.jar:?]
at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.WebDriverConfig.threadStarted(WebDriverConfig.java:152) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-4.10.0.0.jar:?]
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread$ThreadListenerTraverser.addNode(JMeterThread.java:802) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.2]
at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverseInto(HashTree.java:1029) [jorphan.jar:5.6.2]
at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverse(HashTree.java:1012) [jorphan.jar:5.6.2]
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.threadStarted(JMeterThread.java:770) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.2]
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.initRun(JMeterThread.java:758) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.2]
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:264) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.2]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_351]
2023-09-22 10:04:30,452 ERROR o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Error while processing sampler: 'jp@gc - WebDriver Sampler'.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Browser has not been configured.  Please ensure at least 1 WebDriverConfig is created for a ThreadGroup.
at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.sampler.WebDriverSampler.sample(WebDriverSampler.java:65) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-4.10.0.0.jar:?]
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:651) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.2]
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:570) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.2]
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:501) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.2]
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:268) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.2]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_351]*

Answer (score 0):

The error is about Selenium failing to find **Firefox**

You should:

1. Set path to the [geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) in [Firefox Driver Config](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FirefoxDriverConfig/)

   [image]
2. Set full path to your Firefox executable via `webdriver.firefox.bin` property in JMeter's [system.properties file](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization) like:

   ```
   webdriver.firefox.bin="C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe"
   ```

---

Be informed of the following:

1. Using Selenium for performance testing is not recommended [by Selenium developers](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/test_practices/discouraged/performance_testing/)

   > Performance testing using Selenium and WebDriver is generally not advised. Not because it is incapable, but because it is not optimised for the job and you are unlikely to get good results.
2. Using Selenium for performance testing is not recommended by WebDriver Sampler developers

   > Note: It is NOT the intention of this project to replace the HTTP Samplers included in JMeter. Rather it is meant to compliment them by measuring the end user load time.

So it might be a better idea to implement your login using JMeter's [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers

Comment: Thanks, but still facing the same issue after adding the browser full path in the system.properties file and adding the driver path in the Jmeter field , any advice
![screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ivhTTn8Ghwd1Ad2eeOH9wSCj163M1PUu/view?usp=drive_link).